# Error when i import java.util.Arrays

Tags: java, eclipse

When I import `java.util.Arrays`, Eclipse IDE says:

> Arrays cannot be resolved

I've also tried to manually import the Java file. Still am getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you share an entire snippet?

Comment: duplicate? look at [Arrays cannot be resolved? Is this a Build path issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598254/arrays-cannot-be-resolved-is-this-a-build-path-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below directory

```
C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_12\lib
```

In there, you should see files like `rt.jar` which contains the core Java classes and `charsets.jar` which contains many of the extended encoding support for EBCDIC and the CJK languages.

n a parallel bin directory are the executables for Java and related utilities.

If you've installed the Java Development Kit (JDK), in the directory above where you find the libs you will probably find a `src.ja`r file. This can be unpacked either with the `jar.exe` utility, or with a standard zip-style tool, and contains the Java sources to the standard class library.

Some of Java, such as the virtual machine itself, is machine-specific, and will be part of some of the DLL's or EXE's present.

Answer (score -1):

May be you haven't configured Java with your project in IDE.

Please check build path of your project and find whether you have configured JRE/JDK.